# UNIX find: opposite of -newer option exists?

Tags: unix, find

I know there is this option for unix's find command:

```
find -version
GNU find version 4.1

    -newer file Compares the modification date of the found file with that of
        the file given. This matches if someone has modified the found
        file more recently than file.
```

Is there an option that will let me find files that are *older* than a certain file. I would like to delete all files from a directory for cleanup. So, an alternative where I would find all files older than N days would do the job too.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use a `!` to negate the -newer operation like this:

```
find . \! -newer filename
```

If you want to find files that were last modified more then 7 days ago use:

```
find . -mtime +7
```

**UPDATE:**

To avoid matching on the file you are comparing against use the following:

```
find . \! -newer filename \! -samefile filename
```

**UPDATE2 (several years later):**

The following is more complicated, but does do a strictly older than match. It uses `-exec` and `test -ot` to test each file against the comparison file. The second `-exec` is only executed if the first one (the `test`) succeeds. Remove the `echo` to actually remove the files.

```
find . -type f -exec test '{}' -ot filename \; -a -exec echo rm -f '{}' +
```

Comment: Important to note that this logic would be "equals or older than". So, it would include the reference file if it in the path. See, marty's answer below for a better solution.

Comment: Marty's answer will also prevent matching of files with the same name as the test file. I've updated my answer with test that excludes the file being tested against.

Comment: You can also use `-not` instead of `\!`.

Comment: This (updated) answer is incorrect. E.g., `touch -t $(date +%Y%m%d0000.00) fence foo bar; find . ! -newer fence ! -samefile fence` gets `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: @fumiyas the test is finding files not newer than the reference file, i.e. of older or same timestamp, so the result is correct.

Answer (score 7):

You can just use negation:

```
find ... \! -newer <reference>
```

You might also try the `-mtime`/`-atime`/`-ctime`/`-Btime` family of options.  I don't immediately remember how they work, but they might be useful in this situation.

Beware of deleting files from a `find` operation, especially one running as root; there are a whole bunch of ways an unprivileged, malicious process on the same system can trick it into deleting things you didn't want deleted.  I strongly recommend you read the entire "[Deleting Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html)" section of the [GNU find manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you only need files that are older than file "foo" and not foo itself, exclude the file by name using negation:

```
find . ! -newer foo ! -name foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note, that the negation of newer means "older or same timestamp":

As you see in this example, the same file is also returned:

```
thomas@vm1112:/home/thomas/tmp/ touch test
thomas@vm1112:/home/thomas/tmp/ find ./ ! -newer test
./test
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, find doesnt support this 
! -newer doesnt mean older. It only means not newer, but it also matches files that have equal modification time. So I rather use

```
for f in path/files/etc/*; do
    [ $f -ot reference_file ] &&  {
        echo "$f is older" 
        # do something
    }
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
find dir \! -newer fencefile -exec \
  sh -c '
    for f in "$@"; do
      [ "$f" -ot fencefile ] && printf "%s\n" "$f"
    done
  ' sh {} + \
;
```

Comment: Although the code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain what the code does and how it helps.