# Remove files older than the start of the current day

Tags: ksh, aix

I want to use logic that allows to use the find command to find all files older than today's date.

Using the below has a 24 hour timestamp from the current time:

```
find /home/test/ -mtime +1
```

I am trying to achieve a solution that no matter what time it executes in the cron it will check all files older than the start of the day at 00:00. I believe this can be achieved using epoch, but struggling to find the best logic for this.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/ksh

touch -t $(date +%Y%m%d0000.00) fence
find /home/test/ ! -newer fence -exec \
  sh -c '
    for f in "$@"; do
      [[ $f -ot fence ]] && printf "%s\n" "$f"
    done
  ' sh {} + \
;
rm fence
```

Why `find`(1) has no `-older` expression. :-(

[UNIX find: opposite of -newer option exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536837/unix-find-opposite-of-newer-option-exists/60110264)